# Assigning value of list to field using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, fields-attributes

I have used the addfield_management function to add a new field, and I want to assign the value of a existing list like `[1,2,3,...]`to the new field, any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can use arcpy and the [da.UpdateCursor](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm):

> UpdateCursor establishes read-write access to records returned from a
>   feature class or table.

Change commented lines and execute in Python window of ArcMap:

```
import arcpy
feature_class = 'C:\data.gdb\features123' #Change
field_to_update = 'somefield' #Change
values = [1,2,3,4] #Change

list_iterator = iter(values) #Create iterator from list so each value can be fetched using next()

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(feature_class, field_to_update) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        try:
            row[0] = next(list_iterator) #Assign list value to row[0]/field_to_update
            cursor.updateRow(row) #Update the field
        except StopIteration: #If you have less items in list than number of rows in feature class
            print 'List is empty, cant update any more rows'
```